# Why return from bash while loop (in pipe) is not break the enclosed function?

Tags: bash

Consider following script:

```
f1() {
  echo | while true; do
    return 0
  done

  echo "why bash execute this line"          # zsh don't execute this line
}

f1
```

I expect the line "why bash execute this line" is not printed, but bash print this line. It's very strange. I test it in zsh, zsh don't print that line.

Comment: In bash, the `while` loop runs in a pipe, and hence cannot affect the control flow of the main shell process (except via its exit status). zsh runs the last item of a pipe in the main shell if possible.

Comment: @GordonDavisson Thanks very much. Could you share me some official doc link about your statement? I can't find it in https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#Looping-Constructs or  https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/loops1.html

Comment: It's the pipe that causes it, not the `while` loop. See [the GNU bash manual section on pipelines](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Pipelines), next-to-last paragraph. Note that you can change it (make it run the last command in the pipe in the current shell if possible, like zsh) with `shopt -s lastpipe`.

Comment: @GordonDavisson I understand now. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

That `return` only returns from the sub-shell in which `while` is run - you're running `while` via pipe `|`.

Remove `echo |` and it will behave as you expected.

PS: `man bash` or `help return` are your friends.